# Definition of Statistics by Sheldon M. Ross

Tags: definition

Sheldon M. Ross in his book, "Introductory Statistics" states the definition of statistics to be:

> "Statistics is the **art** of learning from data. It is concerned with the collection
> of data, their subsequent description, and their analysis, which often leads to the drawing
> of conclusions."

Why is it an art and not a science? The definition of art states that it deals with creativity, while the definition of science says it deals with the systematic study of a structure, in our case, data.